# Extjs to get all checkbox having id as abcd_xyz_2_*?

Tags: extjs, javascript

I have list of check box as:

test1
      test2
     test3

is it possible to get all the checkbox having name "abcd_xyz_2_*" thru extjs.
so that i can make them checked or unchecked

THanks All

Comment: The checkbox code is as:
                      
<input type="checkbox" id="abcd_xyz_2_1" > test1
                                
<input type="checkbox" id="abcd_xyz_2_2" > test2
                                                   
<input type="checkbox" id="abcd_xyz_2_3" > test3 
                                                  
Its normal html page with no extjs.form.FormPanel or other stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the exact names of the fields you want to check then you can do so with a single call to the containing form's setValues method.

Assuming the checkboxes are in an Ext.form.FormPanel instance named 'form':

```
form.getForm().setValues({
    test1: true,
    test2: true,
    test3: true
});
```

If you still need to set by ID prefix then you can do something like:

```
form.items.each(function( item ) {
    if ( item.getId().indexOf('abcd_xyz_2_') === 0 ) {
        item.setValue(true);
    }
});
```

To manipulate generic checkbox elements in the page which are not contained in any ExtJS panels you can use Ext.query:

```
Ext.each(Ext.query('input[id^=abcd_xyz_2_]'), function( item ) {
    item.checked = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply
But its not a  Ext.form.FormPanel instance named 'form'. Its just a html page

Comment: Check the updated answer for a way to query and manipulate generic elements.